# How can I test error messages including $! without locale issues?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, localization, internationalization, error-handling

In my module, I've got this code:

```
croak("unable to parse file: $!");
```

Then, in my tests, I want to check that I get the right error message when I attempt to parse a file that doesn't exist:

```
like(
    exception { HTML::Tree->new_from_file( "t/non_existent.html" ) },
    qr!^unable to parse file: No such file !,
    "opening missing file failed"
);
```

This works fine, as long as the tests are running in an English locale.  But if you run the tests in a German locale, the error message will come back `unable to parse file: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden` and the test fails.  Other locales have similar issues.

I can't believe this is the first time this has come up, but I can't find any modules on CPAN that address this issue.  Do people simply never test the `$!` part of the error message?  Is there a better solution than changing the test to only check for `qr!^unable to parse file: !`?

Note: this is [RT#77823 in HTML-Tree](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=77823).

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a better solution than changing the test to only check for
>   qr!^unable to parse file: !?

[`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) is a dual variable, i.e. it has string and numeric values. You could use the numeric value in the error message.

Comment: It would be much less useful to have just the number, but I suppose I could include both the number and the string version.  The other problem is that ENOENT is not guaranteed to have the same numeric value on every system.  It just seems like there should be a better solution than this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `%!` to test for errors symbolically as in

```
unless (open my $fh, "<", "/does/not/exist") {
  die "$0: unexpected errno " . ($! + 0)
    unless $!{ENOENT};
}
```

Comment: This would be useful if _in the code that opened the file_ I wanted to make sure it was ENOENT.  But `new_from_file` doesn't care what the error is.  It's in the test script that I tell it to open a filename that doesn't exist, and want to check the result.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tests for a module M should **not** check for features that M isn't
   responsible for.
2. Code that fails because of a non existing file should **not** croak
   "can't parse (file spec)", but "can't find (file spec)".

Answer (score 1):

The way I solve this is to put

```
BEGIN { $ENV{LANG} = $ENV{LC_MESSAGES} = $ENV{LC_ALL} = "C" }
```

in any unit test script that involves such testing. That way, the locale is set to C for the duration of that test, and messages will reliably come in the plain C locale, rather than being localised.

Comment: Unfortunately, this [did not work](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/1c97c28e-bda5-11e1-8f5a-a473c7b3e486).